# Custom list definitions throws an error on activating

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, custom-list

Hi I try to create a custom list definition within visual studio to create based on the listdefinition my own listinstance.

The definition looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <ListTemplate
    Name="Customer"
    Type="10000"
    BaseType="0"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="330"
    DisplayName="Customer"
    Description="A Special Customer with extra Properties."
    Image="/_layouts/images/itcontct.png"/> 
 <Field ID="d300488a-e933-4ba7-8cea-5adf2a211893" Name="ActiveFlag" DisplayName="IsActive"  Type="Boolean"/>   
 </Elements>
```

Now when I deploy it, (for debugging reasons), it works perfectly. 
But when I want to deploy it a second time, I get the following error.

German text:

> Fehler im Bereitstellungsschritt "Funktionen aktivieren": Das Feld mit der ID '{85e87896-cf42-4ca2-bbe7-4f5d6212bc47}', das im Feature '{349fe433-4271-4508-82a7-91382a9a7ec9}' definiert ist, wurde in der aktuellen Websitesammlung oder in einer Unterwebsite gefunden.

In english

> Error in Step "Function activate": The field with the ID '{85e87896-cf42-4ca2-bbe7-4f5d6212bc47}' that is defined in the feature '{349fe433-4271-4508-82a7-91382a9a7ec9}', would already found in this websitecollection.

But I didn't know where I can delete it. 
I did a full cleanup, removing the wsp, cleanup all Trashes (user and site). But I only get that error.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look in the site columns to see if one of your columns is located there?

Comment: Yes I use them in there, but i delete them before I deploy the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a solution that works for me.

I found did this solution. 
[Deploying columns with content types in Visual Studio 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/deploying-columns-with-content-types-in-visual-studio-2010)

After that I could deploy it from visual studio without problems.